# How to stop CreateInstanceSlow from creating new instances of application

Tags: c#, wcf

I have two applications, A and B, and want to send data between the two. Here is my scenario:

- A is always running, and it creates a "Sender service"
- When B runs, it creates its own "Receiver service," and finds and connects to A via the "Sender service"
- B informs A via "Sender service" that B is running and can now accept data to be sent
- A connects to "Receiver service" and sends data to B

This all works well and great, it even shows my connections being made properly. However, when I look to see the data in B, I cannot see it, meaning A is not properly sending the data to B.

When I view the call stack, I see:

```
[Native to Managed Transition]  
[Managed to Native Transition]  
mscorlib.dll!System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(bool publicOnly, bool skipCheckThis, bool fillCache, ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark)  
mscorlib.dll!System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type type, bool nonPublic)  
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingConfigHandler.RemotingConfigInfo.StartupWellKnownObject(string asmName, string svrTypeName, string URI, System.Runtime.Remoting.WellKnownObjectMode mode, bool fReplace)   
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingConfigHandler.RemotingConfigInfo.StartupWellKnownObject(string URI)    
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingConfigHandler.CreateWellKnownObject(string uri)    
...
```

This call stack, along with setting a break point on the default constructor for each of my two services, indicates that new instances are being created, which means that the connections do happen properly, but to random instances being created.

**Any thoughts on how to stop these random instances from being created so that my true instance of A can send my true instance of B the data?** Note: in both of my services, I have already included:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was a mix of the following:

1. `[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]` set in both applications
2. Making the appropriate parts that were being sent between applications `[Serializable]`